# Parsing command line options

Tags: haskell

Here's is the code I'd like reviewed:

```
module Main where

import Control.Monad ( when )
import System.Exit ( exitSuccess )

import Idris.AbsSyntax
import Idris.Error
import Idris.CmdOptions
import Idris.Info
import Idris.Info.Show
import Idris.Package
import Idris.Main

import Util.System ( setupBundledCC )

processShowOptions :: [Opt] -> Idris ()
processShowOptions opts = runIO $ do
  when (ShowAll `elem` opts)          $ showExitIdrisInfo
  when (ShowLoggingCats `elem` opts)  $ showExitIdrisLoggingCategories
  when (ShowIncs `elem` opts)         $ showExitIdrisFlagsInc
  when (ShowLibs `elem` opts)         $ showExitIdrisFlagsLibs
  when (ShowLibdir `elem` opts)       $ showExitIdrisLibDir
  when (ShowPkgs `elem` opts)         $ showExitIdrisInstalledPackages

check :: [Opt] -> (Opt -> Maybe a) -> ([a] -> Idris ()) -> Idris ()
check opts extractOpts action = do
  case opt extractOpts opts of
    [] -> return ()
    fs -> do action fs
             runIO exitSuccess

processClientOptions :: [Opt] -> Idris ()
processClientOptions opts = check opts getClient $ \fs -> case fs of
  (c:_) -> do
    setVerbose False
    setQuiet True
    case getPort opts of
      Just  DontListen       -> ifail "\"--client\" and \"--port none\" are incompatible"
      Just (ListenPort port) -> runIO $ runClient (Just port) c
      Nothing                -> runIO $ runClient Nothing c

processPackageOptions :: [Opt] -> Idris ()
processPackageOptions opts = do
  check opts getPkgCheck $ \fs -> runIO $ do
    mapM_ (checkPkg opts (WarnOnly `elem` opts) True) fs
  check opts getPkgClean $ \fs -> runIO $ do
    mapM_ (cleanPkg opts) fs
  check opts getPkgMkDoc $ \fs -> runIO $ do
    mapM_ (documentPkg opts) fs
  check opts getPkgTest $ \fs -> runIO $ do
    mapM_ (testPkg opts) fs
  check opts getPkg $ \fs -> runIO $ do
    mapM_ (buildPkg opts (WarnOnly `elem` opts)) fs
  check opts getPkgREPL $ \fs -> case fs of
    [f] -> replPkg opts f
    _   -> ifail "Too many packages"

-- | The main function for the Idris executable.
runIdris :: [Opt] -> Idris ()
runIdris opts = do
  runIO setupBundledCC
  processShowOptions opts    -- Show information then quit.
  processClientOptions opts  -- Be a client to a REPL server.
  processPackageOptions opts -- Work with Idris packages.
  idrisMain opts             -- Launch REPL or compile mode.

-- Main program reads command line options, parses the main program, and gets
-- on with the REPL.
main :: IO ()
main = do
  opts <- runArgParser
  runMain (runIdris opts)
```

I'd like to improve it. There are two main related problems.

This code uses `exitSuccess` for early exit. This then leads to a misleading piece of code in `runIdris`.

I'd prefer `runIdris` to look something like:

```
runIdris opts = do
  runIO setupBundledCC
  runIO execute (processShowOptions opts
             <|> processClientOptions opts
             <|> processPackageOptions opts
             <|> idrisMain opts)
```

I think I've worked out a way forward but would love to hear your thoughts.

Comment: You can do `case args of "one" : args -> command1 args; "two" : args -> command2 args; _ -> usage`.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot do that in the real code. I worked out that I can wrap the IO action in a Maybe and use <|>. Additionally, I can wrap the Maybe in a First and use Monoid mconcat.

Comment: It really helps to have at least a worded summary of what the code is doing before jumping straight into a code wall. Please consider adding something to ease the reading experience.

Comment: What is `Opt` type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks fine. There is some replication in `processPackageOptions`, but that's manageable. Your syntactical variant isn't possible, though, since `Idris` isn't an instance of `Alternative`. `type Idris = StateT IState (ExceptT Err IO)` would only be an instance of `Alternative` if `Err` was an instance of `Monoid`, which it isn't.

You could wrap `Idris` in another short-circuiting monad, for example `Either ExitCode (Idris a)` or a transformer variant, but you have to replace all `runIO` with `liftIdrisIO` or similar. That might be too much.

But I concur, the `exitSuccess` in `check` isn't that obvious and should be made more obvious at type level.